# Error in a dynamic text view based on the xml file

Tags: android, textview

i am having a dynamic text view based on the xml file.....Please help me for my code......

my codes

MessageViewPage.java

```
package com.dpn.pack;


public class MessageViewPage extends Activity {

TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
ScrollView sv;
String nickname,body;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.message_view_page);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

    nickname= b.getString("nick");
    body=b.getString("body");

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.message_view_page, null);

    // fill in any details dynamically here
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewSender);
    textView.setText("Sender : "+nickname);

    // insert into main view
    View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.textViewSender);
    insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));



}



}
```

my xml file as follows

message_view_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" 
android:background="@drawable/view">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSender"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewBody"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewSender"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSender"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#F69DD1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonReply"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="Reply" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonListen"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:text="LIsten" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i am having an error in

```
insertPoint.addView(v, 0, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
```

Please any one tell me the solution.....

Comment: What's wrong? Is there an error, and if so, what is your actual error and logcat? Also, "View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.textViewSender)" it appears you're trying to add a blank view to a Textview, why?

Comment: Your scroll view also appears not to be used and you aren't inserting your "body" string anywhere. Is this true, or did you just not post the code where it is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your insertPoint is null. Because you don't set the layout before calling findViewById. So it will not find anything.

You have to call

```
setContentView(R.layout.message_view_page);
```

before.

Answer (score 0):

you use a line `RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.textViewSender);`
in your code but hoe can you get `textViewSender`id with out adding your xml file `message_view_page.xml`
you should add 
`setContentView(R.layout.message_view_page);`
after
`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` this line.